# Recommendation for a multi-instance jquery dialog/overlay

Tags: dialog, overlay, modal-dialog, simplemodal, jqmodal

Ok. had enough of trying out lightboxes, overlays and dialog boxes plugins.  The problem is that very few of them support nested (multiple) dialog open at the same time - a typical requirement in my opinion.

I'm looking for a recommendation for a simple plugin that:

1. supports callsbacks for the usual onShow/onLoad... events
2. supports nested instances i.e. the user open a dialog, clicks a button on it, another dialog opens up while keeping the first one open in the background. In other words, it should support the closure of each instance programatically
3. is NOT the jquery ui dialog plugin

This came about after the big disappointment with SimpleModal's inability to support multiple modal boxes open simultaneously!!!! @EricM, why would you do that to me? why???? ;)

I have narrowed it down to jqModal and the jquery tools overlay. The usage of the latter is weird. Maybe i'm tired but i just don't get it.

So before i dive into jqModal, does anyone have any recommendation based on personal experience that will achieve what I'm trying to do?

thanks

Comment: Hi djeetee - sorry to disappoint ;) I've yet to see a use case that would convince me multiple instances are necessary. You an always use one modal to display different content...

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks for the response. a use case would be one where you'd have a parent-child relationship. say you are entering the details of a meeting using a dialog and at the same time you need to enter the details of some related items (tasks) however you need to be able to go back to editing the meeting data in between. Recycling the same dialog won't work for me because of the complexity and overhead. Hopefully, i'll be able to come up with a UI trick to keep simplemodal cause the alternatives are pretty bad. if not, I hope jqModal is a good plugin. thanks again.

Comment: @Eric Martin, Im in a similar situation. I Like simplemodal its very easy to use. But in some cases I would like to be able to open a modal from another modal. but honestly either way your plugin is really good.